# Prevent RichTextBox from creating new line when enter is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I want to run a method when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed within a `RichTextBox` so I made this code.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
}
```

But I don't want to make a new line when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed. But I can't manage to make that work.

Comment: You can also set the `Multiline` property to `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.Handled = true;` this doesn't allow <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key to make a new line:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
     e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it worked. But I can't use the backspace anymore is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Gewoo...You're Welcome. Why not the `Backspace` also works!

Comment: Are you sure? Because when I press the backspace it won't delete any text.

Comment: @Gewoo...Don't forget brackets `{` and `}` after `if`. It should be like this: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
     e.Handled = true;
}`

Answer (score 4):

Use the Following Code

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
       e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World");
        e.Handled = true; //this will work
}
```

UPDATE : i was late. duplicate answer